# Spark RDD data selection

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I am kind of clueless how to do the following in spark. I have a text file which contains data in the following format:

```
timestamp A,B,C (\n)
A,B,C (\n)
A,B,C (\n)
...
timestamp A,B,C (\n)
A,B,C (\n)
...
```

I read it in an RDD with `sc.textFile(<path>)` which of course treats each line as a separate entry.

How can I separate the timestamp from the first line, so basically create a map of timestamp -> entry1, entry2... where each entry consists of A,B,C? A,B,C are always the same type and *not* the same value, respectively.

Comment: What are entry1 and entry2? Is A, B, C in timestamp line same as A, B, C in next line?

Comment: 'where each entry consists of A,B,C' so entry1 and entry 2 are A,B,C; yes

Comment: If all A, B, C's are same, couldn't you just filter the lines starting with a timestamp and then simply construct the map with those lines?

Comment: same type, not same value

Comment: I don't know of any way to preserve line order in plain spark except for reading in the whole file with `wholeTextFiles`... thinking about it, it would be a nice feature of spark to be able to split on arbitrary chars/strings/regexes when using `textFile`. After all, newline is also just a character.

Comment: The only way, I see in that case is for you to write your own implementation of `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InputFormat<K, V>` and `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.RecordReader<K,V>`use them to read the your files. You will obviously need to take care of splitting your input in such a way that record boundaries are respected. (You don't want one split to contain timestamp and while its associated entries are broken into another split).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only/best way, as hinted to me in the comments, is to use `wholeTextFiles()`. After that, I split the string using a regex of the timestamp and lastly another split on `\n`.